# How-to Embed IP Camera Video in Web Page

Tags: video, streaming, html, ip-camera

I want to streaming live video from an ip camera AVN284A ( avtech ) on html or php page

thanks

Comment: This is a statement, Not a question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the VLC player play the live video successfully?
I'm not sure you RTSP URL is correct, you can check it with VLC.

Comment: thank's for the answer. my RTSP URL is correct i check it in the vlc  also i add pluging quicktime for safary and it work's.
Now i use ipcamlive.com to embding my RTSP and i inject it in iframe in my website. 
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You may enter the website of the IP Camera company and try to find their mailbox or telephone to contact them for website viewing details.

Most of the IP Cameras now can be streamed on the website, like Foscam, Reolink that sort of brands， but the steps might vary.

The general steps are: set up your camera, obtain the IP addresses, access to your network addresses, install the plug-in and then you have your camera working on a website.

Here is an video you might get interested in and it shows all the steps very well: [embed ip camera on the website](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ic_3TLnDoc)